# Where should I ask subjective "game recommendation" questions?

Tags: support, game-recommendations

I have certain consoles, and I'm always looking for recommmendations on certaing genres I like. Is gaming stackexchange the place to ask for these recommendations? Who better than the users here to give good opinions about games?

Say:
What 2 player game can you recommend on GameCube?
What fighting game do you recommend on Nintendo DS?

I know I could spend hours browsing the "big sites" to find their rankings and stuff, but they're never as real as community opinions...

Answer (score 7):

Discussion of what sort of games you might like or are similar to other games really belongs in a community environment where people are able to get a good feel for one another.  There are a number of forums, news groups, chat rooms and message boards that would be ideal for this kind of interaction.

Depending on which of these means you are most comfortable with I would suggest starting there.

By comparison the question "What 2 player game can you recommend on GameCube?" isn't really a question so much as a discussion topic on the subject of 2 player games on the GameCube.  Which are good, which are bad, which are easy to pick up for new players, etc.  While it is being phrased as a question it is not one and not really appropriate for a serious QA site like Gaming.SE.